# Подключить js-скрипты к Spring Boot - проекту

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot

Использую библиотеку Spring Boot. Сверстал элементарную html-страницу(не смотрите на этот код, знаю, он плох, я никогда не верстал да и вряд ли буду, вынужден просто в данный момент). И теперь мне надо подключить js-скрипт из внешнего файла. Почитал, изучил. Сделал следующим образом.

Вот структура проекта в Intellegi idea:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И на всякий случай путь до скрипта  проводнике:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так что папка в IDE *static.js* - это просто сокращение пути в самой IDE.

Далее сама страничка:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/test.js}" src="js/text.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
    body {
        font: 11px 'Verdana';
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    ul {
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }
    ul:after {
        display: block;
        content: ' ';
        clear: both;
        float: none;
    }
    ul.menu > li {
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }
    ul.menu > li > a {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
        color: white;
        background-color: darkgray;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    ul.menu > li > a:hover {
        background-color: black;
    }
    ul.submenu {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        width: 120px;
        top: 30px;
        left: 0;
        background-color: white;
    }
    ul.submenu > li {
        display: block;
    }
    ul.submenu > li > a {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
        color: white;
        background-color: darkgray;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    ul.submenu > li > a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    ul.menu > li:hover > ul.submenu {
        display: block;
    }
    ul.submenu > li > a:hover {
        background-color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    div.blockMenu{
        background-color: darkgray;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

</style>

<body>

<div class = "blockMenu">
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a class="#" >Файл</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href=# onclick="messageBox()" >Открыть</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Sudmenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Sudmenu 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href=#>Menu 2</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href=#>Sudmenu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Sudmenu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href=#>Sudmenu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

<p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'" />
</body>
</html>
```

Простейший код, пока это обычная проба пера. В коде есть обработчик клика по кнопке:

```
onclick="messageBox()"
```

Эта функция берется из скрипта. Сам скрипт подключается здесь:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{js/test.js}" src="js/text.js"></script>
```

И сам код скрипта test.js:

```
function messageBox(){
    alert('Test message');
}
```

Вот и всё. Как и следовало ожидать - функция не вызывается, потому что, как мне кажется, система не может найти скрипт. Вопрос: как правильно прописать путь к скрипту? Или, возможно, как правильно создать систему каталогов, чтобы система определяла скрипт? Спасибо большое.

P.S.: тестировал без spring boot, т.е. обычная web-страница и подключенный скрипт, всё работает без проблем, по кнопке вызывался alert.

**UDP1**

Также, вот ответ браузера:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исследуя эту проблему, я пришел ко мнению, что данная проблема встречается весьма редко. 
Первое, что я добавил - это немного исправленный код, который посоветовал [Константин Полищук](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/317450/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%89%D1%83%D0%BA), за что ему огромное спасибо:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
            "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
            "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/"
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
    }

}
```

Здесь явно указываются пути ко всем местам, где могут лежать статические ресурсы(где ищет Spring). Далее, я добавил аннотацию *RequestMapping*, в класс контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping
@Controller
public class DfdController {
    // TODO
}
```

Сделано это потому, что контроллер по неведомым мне причинам блокирует путь к папке с ресурсами. Поэтому она не загружалась.

Вкупе два метода помогли наконец загрузить внешние скрипты(и в будущем стили). Надеюсь, кому - то это поможет, ибо я провел в поисках и попытках ровно сутки.

Answer (score 1):

Сталкивался с такой проблемой.
Необходимо явно указать, где искать js/css
Пример основного класса

```
 @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application implements WebMvcConfigurer {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }

        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
        }
    }
```

Либо создать класс с аннотацией @Configuration, в котором переопределить метод addResourceHandlers.

Вот пример со Spring Boot и Css/js, можете там посмотреть - https://github.com/KonstantinPM/FileStatistic

Comment: Ваш код помог, но не совсем:) Смотрите ответ ниже. И огромное Вам спасибо!